# Running script existing in another folder - paths

Tags: bash, sh

I have three scripts:

```
-- bin
------ start.sh
-- scripts
------ directory_a
------------ directory_b
------------------ script_1.sh
------------------ script_2.sh
```

*start.sh* runs *script_1.sh*, and then *script_1.sh* runs *script_2.sh*

The problem is with paths:

**start.sh:**

```
path_to_script="../scripts/directory_a/directory_b/script_1.sh";
command="$path_to_script param1 param2";
result=`$command`;
```

**script_1.sh:**

```
path_to_script="./script_2.sh";
command="$path_to_script param1 param2";
result=`$command`;
```

The problem is that *script_1.sh* is looking for *script_2.sh* in wrong directory:
**/bin/script_2.sh**.

I would like not to fix it by passing full path like this (because 'directory_a' name can change):

**script_1.sh:**

```
path_to_script="../scripts/directory_a/directory_b/script_2.sh";
command="$path_to_script param1 param2";
result=`$command`;
```

Answer (score 0):

## common.sh

basedir=

on script start.sh do :

```
basedir= $(dirname $0)
pushd $basedir
absoluteBasedir=$(pwd)
popd

export absoluteBasedir

script1=$(absoluteBasedir)/scripts/directory_a/directory_b/script1.sh
```

## on script 1 :

```
if [[ -z $absoluteBasedir ]]
then
   pushd ../../../
   absoluteBasedir=$(pwd)
   popd
end
script2=$(absoluteBasedir)/scripts/directory_a/directory_b/script2.sh
```

all is done ;)

Comment: path_to_script="../scripts/directory_a/directory_b/script_2.sh";
would works fine too (without absoluteBaseDir) but when I start script_1.sh (immediate) it wouldn't works (script_2.sh not be found).

Comment: No need to use `cd ...; pwd` mechanism. This works : `absoluteBasedir=$(readlink -f $(dirname "$0"))`